# Windows 7 bootmgr is corrupt

Tags: windows, debian

I'm running windows 7 on my main computer and after some power outages this weekend, I woke up to a nice "Bootmgr is corrupt" message greeting me.

I pulled the HDD from my backup rig to boot this one up with the original HDD as a slave.

So here's the question, what's the best way to fix this from the Debian OS I'm running now?

Comment: You can insert a Windows 7 bootable disk and choose repair my computer from the installation screen

Comment: To add to Pratyush's comment -- you're unlike to repair this problem with anythink other than a Windows tool or product although you might be able to copy the bootmgr for another installation if you can determine what file or files that comprise it and where they're stored on the HD.

Comment: [See this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/fixing-bootmgr-is-missing-error-while-trying-to-boot-windows-vista/)